# Submit status to web services dynamically without having any prior knowledge of them

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I'm developing a WCF SOAP web service based on [this schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/oseo/1.0/).

Basically it takes product orders from many clients.

*As part of the submit operation the client is allowed to provide a URL where it expects asynchronous status updates on the order and it's line items.*

**I want to know if anyone has experience with a similar architecture? How did you go about implementing this?**

Can i use a [dynamic web reference as stated here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic)? I would think this won't work very well in this situation. I'm pretty sure i'll need [Chuck Norris](http://www.codesqueeze.com/the-ultimate-top-25-chuck-norris-the-programmer-jokes/) to handle all the exceptions that get throw at the presence of any client service that is not identical or slightly different... even if it does pass schema validation.

The best thing i can think of is building the status object, serializing it into the SubmitResponse request soap message xml then sending it off using curl. something like:

```
curl -d "<my soap message xml>" "http://www.example.com/target"
```

**Any ideas?**

## Question FOCUS

The problem i'm trying to solve is how to submit status responses to web service urls dynamically without having any prior knowledge of them.